# HP G430 G2 OEM Issue

Tags: license, oem

I'm having an issue with a HP 430 G2, I switched out the HDDs so the user could quickly get back working on a functional machine. However the windows activation is now deactivated itself as it doesn't recognise the machine.

There is no sticker on the back of the machine (or ever was) and I can't seem to find the OEM in the BIOS either.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Typically big companies like HP and Dell will attach the windows key to the motherboard BIOS itself, making retrieval difficult. If you can load up the old drive, you may be able to pull the key from it. I'm only leaving a comment since I'm not too sure.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf thanks for your input, any ideas on where I could find it? Been looking everywhere I can think of :/

Comment: If you can load up the old HDD, check under System Properties for the key. The full license could potentially be there.

Comment: Do you mean the notebook is broken but its HDD still works so you removed and connected it into another working machine? If so, you are out of luck as your OEM license is bound to the notebook.

Comment: @guest that is what I mean, but surely I can use the OEM in the device I've now put the HDD in (which also had an OEM)

Comment: @guest please put that as an answer so I can accept it, solved the issue thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get [ShowKeyPlus](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus/releases/download/ShowkeyPlus/ShowKeyPlus.zip) to retrieve OEM key of the current device. Installing this key will do. Or activate via phone with installed key which is the OEM key from old device.